# How to compile a .NET source file into executable using PHP?

Tags: c#, php, .net, linux, compiler-construction

Using C#.NET, i wrote a toolbar which is stored now into  toolbar.cs file.

I want to upload this file to my FTP server with another php file say : compiler.php

i want to be able to compile the toolbar.cs file when i access to

http://www.mysite.com/toolbar.php

Then a new file is created in the same directory containing the ready to download executable.

The reason why i'm trying to do that, is to create a website that create custom toolbars with personalized features for my users.

Comment: I didn't try anything yet because after googling i didn't find any guide or tutorial on how can i compile my .cs file using php

Comment: Is your web server Windows or Linux?

Comment: Even in visual studio you can see what command line you must use if you open the "OUTPUT" window

Comment: Are you trying to compile a single .cs file or will you be providing a full solution?

Comment: @roken My web server is linux

Comment: http://mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler

Comment: @roken I am trying to compile Single .cs which i have used to compile using CSharpcodeprovider & CodeDOM from another C# application.

Comment: You should add that your server is linux to the question itself. One should not have to read comments to answer a question.

Comment: More of a comment on your design/intent.  Perhaps it's best that you do not allow users create custom toolbars via custom written C# (if that's your intent) due to security concerns and possible malicious use.  Instead consider a data-driven model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain no one has written a C# compiler in PHP, so you're going to have to call a compiler via a command line call from your php code.

On Linux, you'll be using the Mono compiler:  http://mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler

Something along these lines (dependent upon the location of toolbar.cs, your required references, and .NET version to target):

```
exec("gmcs -pkg:dotnet toolbar.cs");
```

Comment: if your distribution allows it, use the `mono-csc` link instead of calling gmcs directly. That way you'll keep up when mono keeps changing the name of their compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you, using CSC.exe

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx

Comment: The microsoft compiler isn't designed for linux.

Comment: There is nothing in the comments that mentions Linux, apart from your question?

Comment: Comment #6, posted before your answer:  "@roken My web server is linux – Shikata Ga Nai"

Comment: it was posted at the same time, probably when I was searching for the link....pedantic!